# SSIS: Script task to delete specific rows in Excel

Tags: c#, sql-server, excel, ssis, ssis-2012

I am using a script task to delete particular rows in an Excel in SSIS. Previously it was working fine, then when I try to implement everything again I am getting error in the **.Delete()** codes. Find my code below,

```
            Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application excelApp = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();

            var dir = new System.IO.DirectoryInfo(@"D:\Data_Processing\Input");
            var fullFilePath = dir.GetFiles("*.xlsx").Select(f => f.FullName).FirstOrDefault();

            if (fullFilePath != null)
            {
                Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Workbook workBook = excelApp.Workbooks.Open(fullFilePath);

                foreach (Worksheet sheet in workBook.Worksheets)
                {
                    sheet.Rows[8].Delete();
                    sheet.Rows[7].Delete();
                    sheet.Rows[6].Delete();
                    sheet.Rows[5].Delete();
                    sheet.Rows[4].Delete();
                    sheet.Rows[3].Delete();
                    sheet.Rows[2].Delete();
                    sheet.Rows[1].Delete();
                }

                workBook.Save();
                workBook.Close(false);
                excelApp.Application.Quit();

                System.IO.File.Move(fullFilePath, @"D:\HC_Report.xlsx");

                Dts.Variables["User::FileExistsFlg"].Value = 1;
            }
            else
            {
                Dts.Variables["User::FileExistsFlg"].Value = 0;
            }

            Dts.TaskResult = (int)ScriptResults.Success;
```

And when I try to add **Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel** in the References it is coming with a different icon as below
[image]

Can anyone please help with this ?

Thanks,

Comment: Can you be more specific with the exact error? Is it from Interop? And this code previously worked successfully? And if so… obviously, have you made recent changes?

Comment: yes it is with Interop, it was working, i had to delete the script task and created a new script task and copied over the code. previously it was working.

Comment: @John5, i am getting these errors when i try to build => 
Error: The type or namespace name 'Interop' does not exist in the namespace 'Microsoft.Office' (are you missing an assembly reference?) and **
Error: CS1061 'object' does not contain a definition for 'Delete' and no accessible extension method 'Delete' accepting a first argument of type 'object' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)**

Answer (score 0):

I have manually added the .dll file from this location **C:\WINDOWS\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel\15.0.0.0__71e9bce111e9429c\Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.dll** and then the error disappeared.